# No CMS yet. How can I publish pages and edit pages ONLINE, and nothing more?

Tags: php, content-management-system

So my site does not have a CMS. My site is not like a blog, and really, all I want to do for the most part is just be able to easily publish new pages and edit my code online. It ould just really help my workflow.

I might also want to add a text editor (ckeditor to be specific), but for now, I'll just leave the topic as is.

So yeah, my request seems rather simple. How can it be done?

Comment: CMS stands for Content Management System. Anything that does that (falls under your definition) IS a CMS

Comment: You might sometimes be better served by using a fancy HTML editor with upload capabilities. There are also 'static' blogging desktop apps, etc.

Comment: i too wanted a lightweight just page(based) CMS for my brothers site, but couldn't find anything premade so i made my own. http://lcherone.blogspot.com/p/pk-content-management-systemv01.html - its still a cms tho sorry

Comment: Nice I'll look into it. Is it really easy to integrate into an existing site?

Comment: it was made for a computer illiterate, i couldn't make it much easier, what will happen tho is your need something more once your content grows

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is a very lightweight CMS. Install one.

<sub>(Not that I'd *ever* recommend use of a CMS.)</sub>

Comment: Which one? I've never seen a CMS in which I can edit the mysql and php. EDIT: And why wouldn't you ever recommend the use of a CMS? Just curious.

Comment: @user657847, I've never seen one where you CAN'T edit the source...

Comment: @user657847: Amongst my other wide-ranging skills, I'm a web tools developer. The very idea of creating a website managed by something so constrained, rigid and "off-the-shelf" is apocrypha to me. :) Why not just write your HTML and upload it via FTP?

Comment: In the name of workflow hah. It really does seem like I should have just used a cms like drupal or wordpress from the very beginning. But my stubbornness made me stick with my ways. As it stands, I just find it slightly annoying to upload everything. I'd rather just do everything online, rather than keep switching between dreamweaver and chrome, you know?

Comment: @user657847: But that's how the cool kids do it. It's also really not that much of a burden.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to edit pages as they are out on your server, you can do this easily with [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

It comes with an FTP plugin which supports SFTP.  This should be all that you need.

Comment: Very neat stuff! +1  but I really want a very quick and easy way to create a page online (rather than going thru my host, then cpanel, then file manager). I know it sounds lazy, but it really does become tedious for me. I'd rather just go to a site, log in, and create a new page.

Comment: Now actually looking at notepad... it just seems like a rudimentary code editor (compared to dreamweaver) from the introduction hah (or am I missing something?).

Comment: lol what you need is a......CMS

Comment: I'm not arguing that hah. I just want a very simple cms (no plug-ins needed, just want to be able to edit the code online and maybe have a text editor) that is very simple to integrate for existing sites I suppose.

Comment: @user657847, what do you want?  I have no idea.  If you want to create a new page, much like you do in cPanel, Notepad++ is for you.  If you don't know how to edit HTML on your own, then you shouldn't be using a code editor.  Notepad++ and Dreamweaver are very different tools.  Dreamweaver's code editor is far more rudimentary.  What you want is a WYSIWYG do-it-for-me package.  Why not just use Dreamweaver then?  It can also connect over SFTP.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your site needs a CMS.

Look into WordPress. It's plenty capable for a non-blog website, and it's by far the most polished basic CMS I've encountered.

Comment: As long as you're doing a site that's blog-like. once you try to add in any "decent" quantities of static/semi-static content, WP become a serious pain the rump to work with.

Comment: My site is already made. I just want an ease of workflow. Plus, you can't change the mysql and php using wordpress I don't think.

Comment: @user657847, of COURSE you can edit the source of WordPress...

Comment: It seems like a hassle to integrate wordpress at this point. I want to create my own, simple, cms.

Comment: Then go for it. You'll spend ten times the time and it'll be a tenth as useful. You can absolutely change the code to WordPress - it is open source.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is a good online cms, and it's a platform that can easily build a [simple cms](http://www.60secondcms.com/simple-cms/) website that is manageable to use.